# setting hierarchical property for GXT's ComboBox.setDisplayField

Tags: combobox, gxt

i have a simple extension of a BaseModelData in a form of MyModel, and i can call **new MyModel().getObj1().getObj2()** to get to obj2's string value. i have a number of MyModel instances, so  i would like to populate a ComboBox instance with an obj2 value from each MyModel instance. first, i called ComboBox.setDisplayField("obj1.obj2"), because using such hierarchical property approach works for TextField.setName() cases. then, i took a store which contains all MyModel instances, and set it to a ComboBox via setStore(). however, the combobox is empty. it looks as though setting the aforementioned property via ComboBox.setDisplayField() does not work the same way as it does for TextField.setName(). i tried using my own instance of ListModelPropertyEditor, but without success. so what are my alternatives?

thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about accessing hierarchical data from `ComboBox.setDisplayField()` method, but can you can achieve it by adding a new method say `getObj2()` in `MyModel` class, which will essentially represent `obj1.obj2`.

```
public Obj2 getObj2() {
   return getObj1().getObj2(); //with possible null checks
}
```

Now you can call `ComboBox.setDisplayField("obj2")` and get the work done.

Comment: thank you for your reply, sanbhat. i have have already thought about it, and it will probably be my last resort. the thing is that all of my BaseModelData instances are generated via JAXB, so i would like to keep their hierarchy intact. i was very happy with the fact that Field.setName() accepted values in such hierarchical fashion, but disappointed that ComboBox does not. so i was hoping for a GXT-side solution

Comment: Can you make class Obj1 (which is referenced within MyModel) make extend BaseModelData ?